# how can I draw a chart with uneven Y axis chartjs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I'd like to draw a chart like below. It's a cumulative percentage chart the Y axis scale is uneven looks like normal distribution. Any idea? I can draw a chart with even axis like [20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%]. Is there any way I can specific the values of the y axis? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Hey there. please provide code to recieve help ! Thanks!